# Laravel not displaying debug messages after adding custom error pages

Tags: php, laravel, web, error-handling

I want my Laravel (4.2) site to return some custom error messages (instead of that `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`) when errors occurred, so I added the following:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    return Response::view('errors.500', [], 500);
});

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    return Response::view('errors.404', [], 404);
});
```

to `app/start/global.php`

To test the pages I have temporarily changed: `'debug' => false` in `app/config/local/app.php`

My custom error pages are displaying correctly (when errors occurred). However they are still displaying (instead of a error page with stack traces and error messages) even if I reverted my local development config back to `'debug' => true`.

I tried to paste the following to `app/start/local.php` hoping it would override the global error handling when laravel is in a local environment. But that does not solve the problem.

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);
});

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    Log::error($exception);    
});
```

How can I make laravel display error stack traces again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that as soon if you return something from an `App::error` handler, Laravel will use it as response and stop "bubbling up".

The easiest way is just to check with the `app.debug` config:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);
    if(Config::get('app.debug') !== true){
        return Response::view('errors.500', [], 500);
    }
});

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    if(Config::get('app.debug') !== true){
        return Response::view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }
});
```